# Text message encryption end to end using AES

Tags: android, encryption, aes

End to End encryption in android. I'm trying to implement a chat application in android.

I have tried AES algorithms for the encryption and decryption successfully generated a private and public key

GenerateRsaKeyPair.java class that generating public and private key

```
try {

        // 1. generate public key and private key
       

            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024); // key length
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
            String privateKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            publicKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            // 2. print both keys
            System.out.println("rsa key pair generated\n");
            Log.e("privateKey",  privateKeyString );
            Log.e("publicKey",  publicKeyString );
            isgenerated=false;




    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this code encrypt the message
try {

```
               // 1. generate secret key using AES
               KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
               keyGenerator.init(128); // AES is currently available in three key sizes: 128, 192 and 256 bits.T
               // the design and strength of all key lengths of the AES algorithm are sufficient to protect classified information up to the SECRET level
               SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
               plainText=editTextsend.getText().toString();

               // 2. get string which needs to be encrypted // our case message
               String text = plainText;//"<your_string_which_needs_to_be_encrypted_here>"
               Log.e("string",text);

               // 3. encrypt string using secret key
               byte[] raw = secretKey.getEncoded();
               SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");//PKCS5Padding
               cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
               String cipherTextString = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), Base64.DEFAULT);
               Log.e("ciphertext",cipherTextString);
               // 4. get public key
               X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(publicKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT));
               KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
               PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);

               // 6. encrypt secret key using public key
               Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
               cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
               String encryptedSecretKey = Base64.encodeToString(cipher2.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded()), Base64.DEFAULT);
               Log.e("encryptedSecretKey",encryptedSecretKey);

               // 7. pass cipherTextString (encypted sensitive data) and encryptedSecretKey to your server via your preferred way.
               // Tips:
               // You may use JSON to combine both the strings under 1 object.
               // You may use a volley call to send this data to your server.

           } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

this one decrypt the message successfully
try {

```
        // 1. Get private key
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(privateKey, Base64.DEFAULT));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
        Log.e("secretKey",privateKey+"");
        // 2. Decrypt encrypted secret key using private key
        Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] secretKeyBytes = cipher1.doFinal(Base64.decode(encryptedSecretKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT));
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyBytes, 0, secretKeyBytes.length, "AES");
        Log.e("secretKey",secretKey+"");
        // 3. Decrypt encrypted text using secret key
        byte[] raw = secretKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encryptedTextString, Base64.DEFAULT));
        String text = new String(original, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        Log.e("text",text);
        // 4. Print the original text sent by client
        System.out.println("text\n" + text + "\n\n");


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm expecting that my private key and public should be same for the specific user,But in my code while I'm building my application it generated different private and public key every time so how would I manage the current user previous chat messages and data and it every time for one-one chating and group chat also.
any answer and suggestion would be appreciable.

Comment: First time you need to generate the key and save in db or shared preference. And after this you can get the key from storage and use it rather creating everytime.

Comment: HI abdul user might have multiple devices so when it login onto other divece what happen in that case .

Comment: You may want to organize your code better. WRT to cryptography, try and use an authenticated cipher such as GCM, but please be sure to use a random IV, not a default / zero-ed one. There seems to be no reason at all to encode and then immediately decode the `secretKey`. This is key material, keep it secure.

Answer (score 2):

Store your private key in a `KeyStore`, preferably a system key store for additional protection. For Android, start for instance by reading [this official article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) about the Android key store systems (as it may also impact key pair generation). Storing your PKCS#8 encoded binary private key in persistent storage ("disk") is of course also possible, but storing keys without protection is not recommended. A password stored within an application is the absolute minimum of security that can be provided; usually you try and aim higher.

Your public key can simply be encoded using `getEncoded`. You can then use a `KeyFactory` with algorithm `"RSA"` to retrieve the public key. That public key is usually encoded as an `X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object. X.509 of course is a hint to the X.509 *certificate* specifications: the key is encoded to a compatible binary formatted. Public keys don't need as much protection, as long as they can be **trusted**; attackers should not be able to replace them by their own public keys, of course.

How to trust a public key is the topic of entire books on key management. For asymmetric keys you usually use a PKI - a public key infrastructure - to distribute and validate the status of the keys, wrapped in public key *certificates*. When X.509 certificates are used for this then the PKI is often referred to as PKIX; the TLS certificates in your browser are part of a very large PKIX system.